# Is the following document made from LaTeX?

Tags: pdftex

I know this is probably slightly off-topic,I wonder can LaTex be used to create the following white paper, or for that matter, what software do firms use to make these kind of whitepapers?

To me I guess the biggest obstacle is creating the various graphics used the whitepaper, which seems to be done better in PowerPoint?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bh6e2xeJ73Gg5b-A0HH-ZYahlQSrE4v0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the document's properties: Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 (Macintosh). I guess you can do it with LaTeX, but it's quite a lot of changes from a standard class. You could use TikZ to draw some simple graphics and [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) for the maps (working with SVG files).

PowerPoint is not a good idea, since it lack a lot of functionalities to manage text and drawing.

Another option: [Scribus](https://www.scribus.net), a free alternative to Illustrator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know the document's property includes what is made from. Learn something new today!